# Python Django display gregorian date

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, django-templates, django-views

I have a function that extract data form an mssql db and display the data on a template. currently in my template i have a for loop in my template that loop through the results. i get all the result i wanted, however my date are still display in julian date but i want the dates to be display in gregorian date so that is understandable by the end users.

in the template i have a for loop

```html
<th>date</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>

{%for a in results%}
<td>a.date_entered</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
{%endfor%}
```

view.py

```html
    def bydate_display(request):
        if "selectdate" in request.POST and "selectdate1" in request.POST and "selectaccount" in request.POST:
            selected_date = request.POST["selectdate"]
            selected_date1 = request.POST["selectdate1"]
            selected_acc = request.POST["selectaccount"]
            if selected_date==selected_date and selected_date1==selected_date1 and selected_acc==selected_acc:
                convert=datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
                convert1=datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date1, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
                engine=create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password@servername /db')
                connection=engine.connect()
                metadata=MetaData()
                fund=Table('gltrxdet',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                rate=Table('gltrx_all',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)

                stmt=select([fund.columns.account_code,fund.columns.description,fund.columns.nat_balance,fund.columns.rate_type_home,rate.columns.date_applied,rate.columns.date_entered,fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num])
                stmt=stmt.where(and_(rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num==fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,fund.columns.account_code==selected_acc,rate.columns.date_entered.between(convert,convert1)))

          

                results=connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()

              
                return render(request,'bydatedisplay.html',locals())
```

Comment: Is there are way to convert the date from julian date to Gregorian date from the template.

Comment: i have try to convert the date from my view.py   for a in results:
 test=datetime.date.fromordinal(int(a.date_entered))  but when i pass the variable test to the template. it doesn't display the date range it only display the start date

Comment: What do you mean by displayed as Julian instead of Gregorian? Can you elaborate with a specific example?

Comment: The dates from in database is in Julian dates eg: 736788  .I want to convert that to Gregorian date

Comment: The dates from the db is in Julian. So it's extracted it displays as Julian dates.